# Not able to get Worklight Console

Tags: console, datasource, ibm-mobilefirst, derby

We have installed Worklight server with Websphere Liberty profile.
Installed war file and created derby databases as mentioned in the following url and referenced them in server.xml. I'm getting the below error.

```
Exception thrown by application class    'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized:300'
javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.
Logged Exception: com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSourceException:  
FWLSE0194E: Worklight server cannot be started because of failure while getting a connection from data-source bound to resource reference: jdbc/WorklightDS. Make sure the 
database is up, the credentials are correct and the driver is available for the server. [project bluemine]
at   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:300)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]
```

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to try to answer your question.  Please tell us what procedure you followed to set up the databases, what procedure you followed to deploy the WAR file, and what version of Worklight you are using.  Based on the last question you asked, I am guessing that you are using Worklight 6.1, let us know if that is incorrect.  Just based on what you've provided here, it looks to me like the database was not set up correctly.  You'll need to use the Ant tasks to do this, since the Worklight Server Configuration Tool does not support using Derby as the database.

Comment: You should review this section of the documentation, if you have not done so already:  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_configure_dbs.html

Comment: Issue got resolved. There is a version mismatch of DB and jar files being used. Thanks

Comment: @Vinay, please write that as the answer for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved. There is a missmatch of versions between DB and the jar file being used. Thanks